# Imagemagick throws "width or height exceeds" when converting SVG to PNG with version 6.9.11-60 but not with 6.9.10-23

Tags: imagemagick

I have one server with Ubuntu 20.4 and ImageMagick 6.9.10-23.

The newer server is with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and ImageMagick 6.9.11-60.

I upload a SVG file and want to convert it to PNG and resize it.

```
convert -format png -density 1200 -resize '255x255>' /folder/test.svg /folder/test.png
```

With the old server it works flawlessly.

The newer server with ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 throws:

> convert-im6.q16: width or height exceeds limit /tmp/magick-IXLGAi-fnZE2OS1MPM_W1DzbcXjNnrdl @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3909.
> convert-im6.q16: no images defined /srv/users/hessen/apps/edumaps/public/temp/temp.png @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.

I have compared both `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` files, they have the same settings. Only the old policy.xml states:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MB"/>
```

And the new one states:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MP"/>
```

I changed it to `128MB` but still the same error message.

I also check with `convert -list resource`. The output is for both servers identical, just the old server states `List length: 18.446744EP` and the new server states `List length: unlimited`.

```
Resource limits:
  Width: 16KP
  Height: 16KP
  List length: unlimited
  Area: 128MP
  Memory: 256MiB
  Map: 512MiB
  Disk: 1GiB
  File: 768
  Thread: 64
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Limits can be seen at the [docs](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php). But I use the same file on both servers.

The SVG file is 744 x 1052 pixels.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Your density is too large for the area policy.  You need to specify the policy limits in the units it show.  128 MP is mega pixels and 128 MB is mega bytes.  1 pixel is usually 3 or 4 bytes per pixel (for the number of channels -- RGB or RGBA or CMYK).

Comment: What to change exactly in the settings? But again, with the older ImageMagick version it works. Same settings.

Comment: Try changing 128 BP to 512 MP on the newer system.  Are you the owner of the account?  If this is a shared system, the ISP would have to increase it.  You can only decrease in a shared system.

Comment: I have changed `<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MP"/>` to `<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="512MiB"/>` (and I also tried value `512MB`). – It still throws the same error message.

Comment: Try 512 MP.  As I asked above, are you the owner the Imagemagick install. If this is on a shared server, you cannot increase the limits, but can decrease them. To increase them, the ISP will need to do that.

Comment: It is a dedicated server. I have full root access. I tried `512MP`, I also tried `1GP`. Nothing changes the result (error message) above.

Comment: The error says width or height exceeds limit. So increase those in the policy as well.

Comment: `width` is set to 16KP and `height` is set to 16KP. The SVG image is width 1459px and height 227px. The settings in policy.xml are the same. I even uploaded the policy.xml from the old version to the new version and nothing changed. – I still believe it is a bug in the different versions.

Comment: I have reported the issue as a bug at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6926

Comment: See my comments to your bug report.  You have not made the width nor the area large enough.

Answer (score 3):

Changed these lines:

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
```

to

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="32KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="32KP"/>
```

Now it works. Thanks a thousand @snibgo. Credits: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6926

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is related to ImageMagick's resource limits. Specifically, the "width or height exceeds limit" error occurs when the pixel cache can't be opened, which happens when an image's dimensions exceed ImageMagick's resource limits.

In your case, the issue seems to be with the `Area` resource limit. The `Area` limit is the maximum width * height of an image that can be processed. It's specified in your `policy.xml` file and can also be viewed using `convert -list resource`. In ImageMagick, `Area` is specified in pixels (P) or bytes (B), not in megabytes (MB). So, `128MB` might be causing the confusion.

One of the suggestions from the StackOverflow thread is to try changing the `Area` limit to `512MP` instead of `128MB` or `128MP`. Please note that if this is a shared system, you can only decrease the limits. To increase them, the system administrator or ISP would need to do that.

Here's how you can change it:

```bash
# Open your policy.xml file.
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

# Find the line with <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MP"/>.
# Change it to <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="512MP"/>.
# Save the file and exit.
# Restart ImageMagick.
sudo service imagemagick restart
```

Please try this and see if it resolves your issue. If the problem persists, it might be worth checking if there are other differences in the configuration between your two servers. Also, ensure that the SVG file you’re trying to convert doesn’t have dimensions that exceed the Width and Height resource limits.

I hope this helps!

References:

[ImageMagick Resource Limits](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php)